# Are these queries same?

Tags: sql, oracle

Any pros and cons on the following ways of fetching Employees from HR department? Especially from performance perspective?

```
--1
select * from employee emp
join department dep on emp.depId = dep.id and dep.name = 'HR';

--2
select * from employee emp
join (select * from department dep where dep.name='HR') d
on emp.depId = d.id;

--3
select * from employee emp
join department dep on emp.depId = dep.id 
where dep.name = 'HR';
```

P.S. They all have same query plan and cost

Comment: The first and third are identical (or should be) in terms of performance.  The second is just an unnecessary subquery, which overcomplicates the query, even if it does not affect performance.

Comment: You should check the execution plan to see if they are similar when executing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The idea was to do the join on a table with less rows for the second query

Comment: @shadi Query optimizers are notoriously difficult to trick in this manner. Even if you succeed, often you are mistaken, and end up causing nested loop joins, or worse still, hash joins. Plus, as your data evolve, new plans will emerge anyway. Welcome to the DBA game.

Answer (score -1):

```
--1
select * from employee emp
join department dep on emp.depId = dep.id and dep.name = 'HR';
```

1. For me this is the best query, because you match the data from employee with the department where the data from department is HR named. So you restrict the data from the department table in the join.

   --2
   select * from employee emp
   join (select * from department dep where dep.name='HR') d
   on emp.depId = d.id;
2. This is the baddest query, because the sub query is always costly for the RDBMS. so first the RDBMS will execute the sub query, and then match it with the employee table. Using 3 full reading table.

   --3
   select * from employee emp
   join department dep on emp.depId = dep.id 
   where dep.name = 'HR';
3. This is the option that almost everyone would write, and if you see the execution plan it converts on the same as 1.

Comment: 'They all have same query plan and cost' according to op.

Comment: Most optimizers see right through these derived table tricks. That is how they are able to fold views into the main pipeline.